# Web page display over flash

Tags: jquery, flash, overlay, show-hide

I have a web page with certain tabs and adding flash with jquery

The swf is shown on default, and when you click tab 2, 3 or 4, the content of that page is shown over the flash. (meaning the flash continue to run)

This is what I attempted

```
<div id="game">
            You must have flash installed to view this game
</div>
in javascript file:
swfobject.embedSWF("flash.swf", "game", 500, 500, "7");

$("#tab1").click(function(){
    $("#content-2").hide();
    $("#content-3").hide();
    $("#content-4").hide();
    $("#content-1").show();

});

$("#tab2").click(function(){
    $("#content-1").hide();
    $("#content-3").hide();
    $("#content-4").hide();
    $("#content-2").show();
});
```

The problem with hide is that the flash swf reloads. I need it to remain however it was. How would I do this? A perfect example of what I want is like the tabs in the game City of Wonders on facebook.

EDIT:

I tried doing swfobject.addParam("wmode", "transparent") but this seems to cause error saying addParam doesn't exist.

**SOLVED:**

Ok so I played around a lot and found the problem.

I must not hide the div containing the swf or set it's display to none because this will reload.

The key is wmode=transparent. Now I don't know if addParam has been deprecated or what but this is what worked.

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
params.wmode = "transparent";
var attributes = {};
swfobject.embedSWF("flash.swf", "game", 580, 680, "8","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

after this all I do is hide all the divs(except the one containing the swf), whichever div I do .show to will be shown. No need to use z-index because if I do .show to the div the swf is in(even if it is not hidden) it will put it on top ! perfect !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wmode=transparent`

as parameter on the movie probably will solve the issue, try it out and let me know!

Comment: i tried doing swfobject.addParam("wmode", "transparent") and now my .clicks dont do anything. I tried playing around with z-indexes instead of using show/hide and no luck either :(

Comment: This worked, but yeah also you don't even need to hide the div containing swf. Just hide/show the ones that display over it

Answer (score 0):

Try to change css 'display' value, or change z-index to "hide" your div under the page's div instead of disappearing it.

Comment: i think show/hide is short for changing display value, neither worked for me :( changing display to none gave me same effect

Comment: Ave, did you try modifying these for your 'game' div? I assume that is where you show your Flash movie?

Comment: Yeah the flash is always in front unless you change it's wmode, z-index doesn't matter. And display: none; or jquery hide() on the wrapper will still cause the swf to reload